# Facebook Local Currency Payment directly refund without allow developer to handle dispute

Tags: facebook-graph-api, local, payment, currency

After I done integrating my apps with Facebook local currency payments, I asked my colleague to purchase in-game items and later dispute the transaction for testing purpose.
I did receive the real time update on dispute, but soon after 4 seconds, I receive another update that Facebook had initiated refund.

I thought developer should be given 72 hour to handle dispute and verify the dispute is legitimate?

Answer (score 0):

Here is what the doc says:

> As mentioned earlier on this page, Facebook's philosophy regarding
>   payment disputes is that we will handle all disputes that imply that
>   the user is requesting a full refund of the transaction (i.e. the "I
>   accidentally purchased an item I do not want" option). On the other
>   hand, if the user request is aimed at receiving the item or in-app
>   currency that they've purchased, we will route the dispute to the
>   developer (i.e. the "I didn't receive the game item(s) I purchased"
>   option).

So I guess there is no 72 hour disputes (and no corresponding callbacks) when user selects "correct" options.